# My iPad's keyboard is split in the middle. How can I revert to a normal default keyboard?

Tags: ipad

My iPad's keyboard is split in the middle.

1. How did this keyboard change to a divided keyboard (like those virtual ergonomic ones)?
2. How can I revert back to the normal default keyboard?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Pinch on the screen over they keyboard to put it back together. Basically swipe inwards from both sides to put it together and swipe outwards from the middle to split it.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to get it back to normal is to put your right thumb on the right part of the keyboard and your left thumb on the left side and then push them together, to pull the keyboard apart simply pull your thumbs apart. I hope this helps